# Where can I find the efficiency of my heat pump with respect to temperature?

Tags: energy-efficiency, heat-pump

I can heat my house either with a standard gas heater, with a documented efficiency of 0.9, or with an heat pump, with a standardized coefficient of performance ([Seasonal Coefficient of Performance](https://www.daikin.co.uk/en_gb/faq/what-is-seasonal-efficiency--scop-and-seer-.html)) of 4.61

I pay my gas 0.045€/kwH, and my electricity 0.16€/kwH => Electricity is 3.5 times more expensive than gas, and I should use my heat pump as long as the efficiency is above 3.5.

However, it is well known that heat pump performance is heavily impacted by temperature, and there is probably a point where the efficiency decreases so much that gas heating is more economical.

**Is there an easy way to get hands on an efficiency graph for any heat-pump that my Google-fu failed to find (or at least mine, a Daikin 3MXM52N)**

Comment: A few governmental rating programs produce (sparse) point data on this (for the specific brands/models they have tested). Graphs you usually are at the mercy of the manufacturer, if they produce them, and if you believe their claims (or at least can see if they match any point data you can source elsewhere.) It should be straightforward, but IME it's not.

Comment: Apparently they us e a swing compressor and efficiency data can be found at https://docs.lib.purdue.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=3297&context=icec

Comment: From https://www.daikin.co.uk/en_gb/products/3mxm-m.html: "Seasonal efficiency values up to A+++ in cooling and A++ in heating thanks to its up-to-date technology and built-in intelligence" so you just have to figure out how good is A++ and A+++

Comment: Have you looked at how [balance point calculations](https://www.energyvanguard.com/blog/simple-way-calculate-heat-pump-balance-point/) are done?